# Some files got deleted randomly in Ngmodules folder in the angular app and getting some errors?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12

Ngmodule: folder in angular . Some files got deleted randomly.
Error: ngmodule/typescript location . Check the "main" in angular.json .

How to solve this issue ?.

I solved this issue :

1. Deleted the node_Modules  folder in the angular app.
2. Then I executed npm install command .
3. Now the node_modules folder is created.

Comment: There's not much we can say here other than: Undelete those files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have solved the issue, please post the solution as an answer post rather than editing your question post. Have a great day :D